# ruby parse HTTParty array - json

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, httparty

Still new to Ruby - I apologize in advance if this has been asked.

I am using HTTParty to get data from an API, and it is returning an array of JSON data that I can't quite figure out how to parse.

```
#<Net::HTTPOK:0x1017fb8c0>
{"ERRORARRAY":[],"DATA":[{"ALERT":1,"LABEL":"hello","WATCHDOG":1},{"LABEL":"goodbye","WATCHDOG":1}
```

I guess the first question is that I don't really know what I am looking at. When I do `response.class` I get `HTTParty::Response`. It appears to be a Hash inside an array? I am not sure. Anyway, I want a way to just grab the "LABEL" for every separate array, so the result would be `"hello", "goodbye".` How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to parse it per say. what you could do is replace ':' with '=>' and evaluate it.

example: say you have `["one":"a","two":"b"]`, you could set s to equal that string and do `eval s.gsub(/^\[/, '{').gsub(/\]$/, '}').gsub('":', '"=>')` will yield a ruby hash (with inspect showing {"one"=>"a", "two"=>"b"})

alternatively, you could do something like this

```
require 'json'

string_to_parse = "{\"one\":\"a\",\"two\":\"b\"}"

parsed_and_a_hash = JSON.parse(string_to_parse)
```

parsed_and_a_hash is a hash!

Comment: this is great, and i see where it is going. for some reason, i can't install the json gem (whole other issue). when i get a ruby hash with the regex, how do I access the elements in the hash? how would i list all of one key's value?

Comment: if you have a hash, say from my example, you would access the value corresponding to the key "one" with `parsed_and_a_hash["one"]`. to see all the keys, make a call the "keys" method like this: `parsed_and_a_hash.keys`

Answer (score 0):

If that's JSON, then your best bet is to install a library that handles the JSON format.  There's really no point in reinventing the wheel (although it *is* fun).   Have a look at [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/ruby-json.html#lib) article.

If you know that the JSON data will always, always be in exactly the same format, then you might manage something relatively simple without a JSON gem.  But I'm not sure that it's worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

If you're struggling with the json gem, consider using the Crack gem.  It has the added benefit of also parsing xml.

```
require 'crack'
my_hash_array = Crack::JSON.parse(my_json_string)

my_hash_array = Crack::XML.parse(my_xml_string)
```